# Build Lookup Data using Bootstrap 3 Modal Dialog

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a lookup data using Bootstrap Modal Dialog. Upon user clicked "select link" from a list of record in the Modal Dialog, the selected Client Name will be pass to textbox in the Main Page. Below is the code

**HTML file (Main Page)**

```
<script>
        $(function () {

            var viewModel = {
                workorder: ko.observableArray(@Html.Raw(Model.WorkOrdersJSON)),
            }

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        });
</script>
@using (var form = Html.Bootstrap().BeginForm(new { @class = "form-horizontal", id = "myForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Partial("_ClientInfo")
    </div>
}
```

**Html.Partial file (Modal Dialog)**

```
<label for="inputClientName" class="col-lg-2 control-label" id="clientname" >Client Name</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="clientName">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Search Client</a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">List of client</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <!-- Modal body-->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="page-header">
                                    <h1 id="tables">List of Work Order</h1>
                                </div>

                                <div class="bs-example">
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>#</th>
                                                <th>Report Date</th>
                                                <th>Category</th>
                                                <th>Subject</th>
                                                <th>Description</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody >

                                            <!-- ko foreach: workorder -->

                                            <tr data-bind="click: $parent.selectTag">
                                                <td>
                                                    <span id="test" data-bind="text: wO_Id"></span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span data-bind="text: wO_Date"></span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span data-bind="text: wO_Category"></span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span data-bind="text: problem_Subject"></span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span data-bind="text: problem_Description"></span>
                                                </td>   
                                                <td>    
                                                <a href="#" class="tag-select">Select</a>    
                                                </td>                                     
                                            </tr>

                                            <!-- /ko -->
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /example -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /model body -->

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 1):

After spending a few hours on this issue, finally i figured it out. Below is my new code

HTML file (Main Page)

```
<script>

        function ConfigsViewModel() {
            var self = this;

            this.clientinformation=ko.observableArray(@Html.Raw(Model.ClientInfoJSON));
            this.Selected = ko.observable(this.clientinformation()[0]);

            this.SelectConfig = function (Config) {
                self.Selected(Config);
                $("#clientName").val(this.clientName); 
                $("#hideclientId").val(this.clientId); 
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            }
        }

        ko.applyBindings(new ConfigsViewModel());

</script>
```

Html.Partial file (Modal Dialog)

```
<label for="inputClientName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Client Name</label><input id="hideclientId" type="hidden" />
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="clientName">

        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Search Client</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">List of client</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <!-- Modal body-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">

                        <div class="bs-example">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="tableClient">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>#</th>
                                        <th>Client Name</th>
                                        <th>Category</th>
                                        <th>Subject</th>
                                        <th>Description</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>


                                    <!-- ko foreach: clientinformation -->
                                    <tr data-bind="click: $parent.SelectConfig">
                                        <td>
                                            <span id="test" data-bind="text: clientId"></span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span data-bind="text: clientName"></span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span data-bind="text: wO_Category"></span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span data-bind="text: problem_Subject"></span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span data-bind="text: problem_Description"></span>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <!-- /ko -->

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                        <!-- /example -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /model body -->

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```